# Executing MySQL procedure from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mysql-database

I wanted to 'Call' MySql (Azure) Procedure from Azure Data Factory.  I can with SQL Server Procedure from ADF but not MySQL Procedures.

How can this be achieved, are there any other service which can be integrated with ADF to call this mysql procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can call the Azure SQL for MySQL stored procedure in query operation at Source.

For example, I create a stored procedure and call it successfully in Data Factory:
[image]

Query operation: `Call GetData(`):

[image]

There are many limits that the stored procedure must be query or have return value.

Others have posted the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/41103823-mysql-stored-procs):
[image]

We can continue to vote it up and Data Factory could see it. Hope they can think about provide the full stored procedure feature support.

Comment: Thanks Leon.  I did figured out this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup Activity if you just need to call the Stored procedure. I tried today for the stored procedure (which update the table) and it worked.